# Some textboxes in Reactive Form are not clearing using Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 6 and Reactive Forms to create a schedule that has 2 sections. The location section has an origin and destination textbox and the trip section which is a nested object in the schedule also has an origin and destination textbox. When the user creates a schedule, a popup displays to confirm the schedule was created. They have an option to click the Create Schedule button on the popup to create another schedule. This popup closes the dialog and creates a new schedule object and assigning the object to the component schedule object in the HTML.

The problem is the origin and destination fields in the location section do not clear on the screen.  But the origin and destination fields in the trip section do clear.
The schedule is defined as a location and trip section object:

```
  <app-location-section [schedule]="schedule"></app-location-section>
  <app-trip-leg-section [schedule]="schedule"></app-trip-leg-section>
```

This is the location origin html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-25 d-block">
        <mat-label id="mat-card__origin-id" class="label">{{
          ORIGIN_LABEL
        }}</mat-label>

      <input
        type="text"
        matInput
        formControlName = 'originControl'
        [matAutocomplete]="autoOrigin"
        id="mat-card__origin-input-id"
      />
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoOrigin="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of originOptions | async"
          [value]="option"
        >
          {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    
      <mat-error *ngIf="scheduleForm.controls['originControl'].hasError('invalid')" id="mat-error__origin">
        Please select a valid location
    </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the typescript code for the origin. It has getters and setters

```
get originId(): string {
    return this.schedule.originId;

  }

  set originId(value: string) {
    this._originId = value;
    this.schedule.originId = value;
    this.updateScheduleObject();
  }
```

This is the origin code from the trip section:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"class="w-25 d-block">
      <mat-label class="trip-origin-label">{{ ORIGIN_LABEL }}</mat-label>

      <input
          type="text"
          matInput
          formControlName = 'triplegOriginControl'
          [matAutocomplete]="autoTripLegOrigin"
          class = 'trip-origin-input'
      />

      <mat-autocomplete #autoTripLegOrigin="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of triplegOriginOptions | async"
          [value]="option"
        >
          {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <mat-error *ngIf="triplegForm.controls['triplegOriginControl'].hasError('invalid')">
        Please select a valid location
    </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the typescript code that is only used when initialized:

```
ngOnInit():void {
  this.triplegForm = new FormGroup({
    "triplegOriginControl": new FormControl(null, [ValidateLocation(this.locationArray)]),
    "triplegDestinationControl": new FormControl(null, [ValidateLocation(this.locationArray)])
  });

  this.triplegForm.get('triplegOriginControl').valueChanges.subscribe(
    (value) => this.leg.originId = value
  );

  this.triplegForm.get('triplegDestinationControl').valueChanges.subscribe(
    (value) => this.leg.destinationId = value
  );

  this.triplegOriginOptions= this.triplegForm.get('triplegOriginControl').valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(""),
  map((value) => this._filter(value)));

  this.triplegDestinationOptions= this.triplegForm.get('triplegDestinationControl').valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(""),
  map((value) => this._filter(value)));

   this.fetchData();
  }
```

This is the code when the confirmation dialog closes a new schedule is created

```
openDialog(response: ScheduleDTO): void {
    let dialog = this.dialog.open(ScheduleCreationConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      width: '60%',
      height: '80%',
      data: response,
      disableClose: true
    });

    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe( () => {
      let sampleSchedule = new Schedule();
      sampleSchedule.tripLegs = [new TripLeg()]; 
      this.schedule = sampleSchedule;
    });
```

After the confirmation dialog is displayed and I click Create Schedule, I put a watch on the 'value' field in the location section and it is listed as 'undefined' yet there is a value in the textbox.  When I start to enter data in the textbox field, the value is set to the value in the textbox field.
What field in the html still has the old value yet the trip section is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

The input you provide to the child component is reference binded.
So as per my suggestion you should access the schedule object using getter and setter in the child component.

So in the location component that is the component with selector  you just add the following code to handle the input variables.

Replace your input line of code with the following lines:

```
private _schedule: any;
  @Input()
  public get schedule(): any {
    return this._schedule;
  }
  public set schedule(value:any) {
    this._schedule= value;
  }
```

Comment: You mentioned that the child component is reference bound.  Is the location component not bound? I thought it was. How do I bind it?  I also added some of the typescript code to show the getting and setting.  The location component has getter and setter but the child component does not have it

Comment: In your component LocationSection you must have written @Input. Please replace that with the lines shown above.

Comment: In the typescript file of the location component, there is an **@Input** line.  It is this:
**@Input()
  schedule: Schedule;**

Is this where I am to replace the code or in the html file?

Comment: Yeah you are correct. This is where you replace the code.

Comment: I tried to add the suggested code but it was not even creating the html page.  We have the schedule object defined **schedule: Schedule. So I used that object in the return statement of the get and set functions.  I had to rename of the functions to **get scheduleObject()** because it was throwing a compilation error.

Comment: Please share your code using editor so that i can see what you have tried.